# Duration of Notice Period in the US and in the rest of the world

Tags: united-states, notice-period, germany

Out of curiosity, I read some of the threads here and what really suprised me were the discussions about the notice periods of only one or two weeks. I'm from germany and so far, I always had notice periods of at least two or three months and I found it completely normal and also reasonable. I just founded a tech company and if my employees could leave with just two weeks notice, It would be very hard to build a new product (development time of our current machine is about 2 years).

What is the average duration in contracts? How do companies deal with the loss of personal experience? How much time is invested in documentation?

I hope this question is not too much opinion based, I just want to understand the american way of thinking in this area a bit better.

Comment: I'm also voting to close. An inventory of rules might have some use, but for it to be really useful, it would have to address the legislation issues for each country - which makes it off topic (legal issues), and maybe even too broad.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is on hold. The question is about regulations and methods based on countries and not for a specific company. Is is also no legal advice because no legal question was asked. Could someone explain why the quoted reasons apply here?

Comment: There are multiple questions in your question. You may have better luck if you ask just *one*. For instance, perhaps along the lines of "Notice periods in the US are only two weeks. Coming from Germany, this appears very short in order to transfer skills & knowledge. If one of my key employees left on two weeks' notice, I would not be able to find a replacement quickly, let alone transfer knowledge. *How do US companies deal with the loss of personal experience?*"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19582/discussion-on-question-by-foobar-duration-of-notice-period-in-the-us-and-in-the).

Comment: **comments removed** :  Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. On Workplace SE, comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, but WTF? Is this the way workplace.stackexchange works? If there is a nice discussion (but maybe at the wrong place) it is just deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I currently work in Canada but have worked in the US previously. In both places, a 2 weeks notice is common as a way to tie up loose ends relatively quickly. For some higher up positions like a director the notice period may be higher assuming the departure is somewhat amicable and hand off of current work could take some time.

Contracts can vary from as little as a couple of weeks to as long as about a year where in Canada there will often be a break before continuing on as there is a risk of the contractor being classified as an employee by the government. Some people may have contract renewals as in one place I worked for a few years, the contractor was there before I started and still there when I left though he did take a month break each year as part of his process.

Projects are generally structured so that there can be the re-allocation of resources and sometimes the breaks come where a contractor take a bit of a break before coming back to the project after what would seem like a long vacation for an employee. Documentation can vary though most places I know will do minimal documentation as there isn't much value seen in that though I did have a place where I did a fair bit on documentation though I did have the challenge that my visa was expiring and I would be leaving the company for that reason.